# How to check mail send success or not when using mail() PHP?

Tags: php, email

How to check mail send success or not when using mail() PHP ?

I use this code for send mail to user , But i want to know how can i check send mail status success or not on this code ?

```
<?PHP
include("connect.php");
$to      = "test@example.com";
$subject = "Subject";
$message = "Message";
$headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n"; 
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'From: EXMAPLE <noreply@example.com>' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Return-Path: return@example.com' . "\r\n";
mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers, '-freturn@example.com');
?>
```

Comment: From the manual `Returns TRUE if the mail was successfully accepted for delivery, FALSE otherwise.` So you can simple do a an `if`

Comment: how to get return value ?

Answer (score 2):

Something like this.

```
if(@mail($emailRecipient, $subject, $message, $headers))
    {
      echo "Mail Sent Successfully";
    }else{
      echo "Mail Not Sent";
    }
```

From the [docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php)

> Returns TRUE if the mail was successfully accepted for delivery, FALSE
>   otherwise.
>
> It is important to note that just because the mail was accepted for
>   delivery, it does NOT mean the mail will actually reach the intended
>   destination.

Answer (score 1):

`mail()`  returns boolean value depending on whether the mail was successfully accepted for delivery. Add an `if` condition to check whether `mail()` returns `TRUE` or `FALSE` like shown below.

```
if(mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers, '-freturn@example.com'))
  echo "Success";   // on TRUE
else
  echo "fail";     // on FALSE
```

Comment: this not work always. you have to set `sendmail` too. otherwise it alway print success and you didn't get any email

Answer (score 0):

```
if(@mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers))
{
  echo "Sent";
}else{
  echo "Failed";
}
```

This should do the job you desire.

Answer (score 0):

Please try like this

```
<?PHP
include("connect.php");
$to      = "test@example.com";
$subject = "Subject";
$message = "Message";
$headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n"; 
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'From: EXMAPLE <noreply@example.com>' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Return-Path: return@example.com' . "\r\n";
if(mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers, '-freturn@example.com')) {
   echo "Your mail sent successfully";
} else {
   echo "Your mail was not sent something wrong";
}
?>
```